# Build uWebSockets on Windows 10 with CMake

Tags: c++, build, cmake, uwebsockets

I want to use [uWebSockets](https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets)(UWS) in my C++ project to transfer images over the network. The setup will be running on multiple operating systems, so the best way of creating the build files seemed like using CMake.

However, I am new to CMake and having a hard time building UWS. I don't understand how to start working with the official repository on Windows 10, so I found [another repository](https://github.com/jchdng/uWebSockets) that includes a `CMakeFiles.txt` file and some of the dependencies (*openssl, zlib, libuv*, but it doesn't include *uSockets* for some reason). The root [`CMakeFiles.txt`](https://github.com/jchdng/uWebSockets/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) includes:

```
[...] 

find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)

find_path(LIBUV_INCLUDE_DIR uv.h)
find_library(LIBUV_LIBRARY NAMES uv uv1)

[...]
```

It looks straightforward, but when I try to run `mkdir build && cd build; cmake ..`, it cannot find `OpenSSL`. Here is the error message it spits out:

```
[...]
[cmake]   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenSSL" with any
[cmake]   of the following names:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     OpenSSLConfig.cmake
[cmake]     openssl-config.cmake
[...]
```

The above error message suggests that I need to set up a config file for each of these libraries. Yet, if I understand the [`find_package` docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-procedure) correctly, the command itself searches the library in various locations under the root folder. What kind of a folder structure does the `find_package` need in order to work?

More generally, am I wasting my time with this alternative repo? Is there a better way of using UWS with Windows 10? The official repo has [a question](https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets/issues/898) about how to use it on Windows but I don't understand how that's an answer to the question. It only points to [this page](https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets/blob/master/misc/FAQ.md) where it says any specific build systems will not officially be supported.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you see this wiki page: https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets/wiki/Misc.-details ? looks like there may be a Visual Studio project (VC++.vcxproj) somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing dependencies with `add_subdirectory` seems like a good way around this. When I ran cmake, I was receiving LNK2019 Error. I realized the following code snippet I found online was causing the problem, and the system works when I delete it.

```
if(MSVC)
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG} /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrt.lib")
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")
endif()
```